# Impala: Co-locating blocks to prevent network traffic

Tags: java, hdfs, cloudera, impala

My goal is to prevent unnecessary data exchange between nodes if the needed blocks are on the same node (co-located).

I have two tables, A and B (simplified example):

```
Table A    Table B
ID         ID 
0          0 
0          0
0          1
1          
1
```

Table A consists of two parquet files which result in two blocks:

```
Block1      Block2
ID          ID
0           1
0           1
0
```

The same for Table B:

```
Block1      Block2
ID          ID
0           1
0
```

Let's say, I have two nodes N1, N2. TableA-Block1 and TableB-Block1 are on N1 and TableA-Block2 and TableB-Block2 are located on N2.

If I have a query like

```
Select * from TableA INNER JOIN TableB on TableA.Id=TableB.Id
```

Impala would exchange the data between both nodes. It would look similiar to this example:

[image]

The plan looks the same if blocks are randomly distributed across the cluster, so Impala does not take any advantage of the "local" blocks.

I want Impala to do a local join between TableA-Block1 and TableB-Block1 as well as for TableA-Block2 and TableB-Block2 to prevent network traffic. How could I do this in Impala?

Answer (score 0):

To be 100% sure the tables are stored within the same node, you could UNION the tables into one table but create a new column called "original table name" and set this to either table A or table B depending on the data's origin. Then you can pull both bits of data from this table and join them.

Also this makes for interesting reading and presents the point that data locality is actually not that much more efficient on Hadoop: 
https://www.bluedata.com/blog/2015/05/data-locality-is-irrelevant-for-hadoop/

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! If I understand the idea of bucketing correctly, I have to define the number of buckets by table creation time. In my example, I would set it to 2 since I have 2 nodes.

So it should result in bucket0 with IDs 0, 2, 4...and bucket1 with IDs 1,3,5... if I'm correct.

But how can I guarantee that the files/buckets are located on the correct node? Isn't this handled by HDFS itsself? HDFS could locate both buckets (=blocks?) on the same node instead of bucket0 on node0 and bucket1 on node1.

Comment: And If I do the same with the other table (B), Impala would do a local join (tableA-bucket0 with tableB-bucket0 etc.)?

Comment: Have looked into this in more detail today and block assignment to nodes is random, even when using bucketing. So it seems the best solution is to combine the dataset as I specified in my answer. I will amend my answer now.

Comment: Yes, the blocks are distributed randomly. You're correct with your UNION solution to guarantee the right bucket/block placement. But even then, the query plan looks the same as shown above (with the two exhange boxes). How can I tell Impala to do the joins locally? Or does Impala always show the exchange although everything is done locally and I have to look for the network throughput (should be 0 MB/sec then, except for the final result when all join results are sent to the "final" node)?

I know this article but this depends on your network of course. I would like to get this done.

Comment: How are you quantifying the impact of this exchange of data? I.e. How can you tell the level of impact exchanging data across the network would have?

Comment: I want to improve the execution time of my query which is basically a join over three tables with huge data (pb level). It's a research project.
So actually the network throughput should be 0 as I mentioned above (except for the last step). Unfortunately it's still ~100MB/sec in my test environment so that there seem to be multiple exchanges. Any idea how I can prevent this / tell Impala to prevent the exchange?

Comment: Any idea? I still couldn't figure this out.